# how to pivot Spark dataframe table?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have this table of 3 columns:

```
+---+----+----+
| id|type| val|
+---+----+----+
|  1|   A|   0|
|  2|   A|   0|
|  4|   A|   0|
|  2|   B|   1|
|  4|   B|   1|
+---+----+----+
```

and I would like to transforme it to something like:

```
+---+----+----+
|   |   A|   B|
+---+----+----+
|  1|   0|   -|
|  2|   1|   1|
|  4|   0|   1|
+---+----+----+
```

I tried this but didn't work:

```
val data_array = data.pivot(cols=['type'],rows=['id'],values='val')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df.groupBy("id").pivot("type").agg(first("value")).na.fill("-").show
```

df is the dataframe created from the test data file